# Python, can't import file from another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, directory

Structure:

```
folder "a":
     __init__.py
     car.py
folder "b":
     tad.py
```

And I do in tad.py:

```
from a.car import *


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

What can I do??
EDIT:
I added init to the top level folder, and now throws this error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000031bc (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I want to resolve this with the classic importing syntax, not sys.path.insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
from .a.car import *
```

The leading dot goes one directory up in folder hierarchy.